Jenkins pipeline change github check context from continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge
I have two Organisation folders within Jenkins. These poll a number of repositories, and both have different pipelines which run different scripts. When these two pipelines are run on the same commit, only one status gets published with the context continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge. The Jenkins instance is unable to receive inbound traffic, so only detects changes through polling.
I think I need to change the context of one of the pipelines from continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge such that in Github, it will show two build statuses. How can I do that?
I tried adding this function to the pipeline:
void setBuildStatus(String message, String state) {
  step([
      $class: "GitHubCommitStatusSetter",
      reposSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource", url: "<https_repo_url>"],
      contextSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource", context: "ci/jenkins/new_context"],
      errorHandlers: [[$class: "ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler", result: "UNSTABLE"]],
      statusResultSource: [ $class: "ConditionalStatusResultSource", results: [[$class: "AnyBuildResult", message: message, state: state]] ]
  ]);
}

which is called by
setBuildStatus("In Progress", "PENDING")

But I see:
[Set GitHub commit status (universal)] PENDING on repos [] (sha:2b785f1) with context:ci/jenkins/new_context in the log.
